Realization of fundamental group endomorphism
My question is :
For any pointed topological space $X$, is every homomorphism from $\pi_1(X)$ to $\pi_1(X)$ realizable by a pointed continuous map from $X$ to $X$?
For example, when two spaces are allowed to be different, the counterexample is answered here.
: The fundamental group functor is not full. Counterexample? Subcategories with full restriction?
But I cannot find counterexample when the two spaces are the same.
Will there be a counterexample? Any kind of hint or reference is welcomed.

You mean pointed spaces and pointed maps, right? The fundamental group is not a functor on topological spaces. I also fixed the title btw.

Oooh I think you are right.. I wasn't sure I was using the right terms. Thanks for your clarification!

A more refined version of your question would be with the extra assumption that the homomorphism "extends" to an endomorphism of cohomology rings (with arbitrary coefficients).

This answer is probably too complicated and it uses a bit of rational homotopy theory, but it's the simplest I could construct.
Take the free graded-commutative algebra $A$ (over $\mathbb Q$) generated by 4 elements $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ of degree $1$ and by an element $\omega$ of degree $2$. Define a differential on $A$ via
$$d\alpha=d\beta=d\gamma=d\delta=0$$
$$d\omega = \alpha\beta\gamma.$$
As you can easily check, there is no endomorphism $f$ of the dgca $(A,d)$ such that
$$f(\gamma)=\delta,\ f(\delta)=\gamma,\ f(\alpha)=\alpha,\ f(\beta)=\beta.$$
Indeed, $f(\omega)$ would have to be of degree $2$, i.e. of the form $f(\omega)=c\omega +\rho$ for some $c\in\mathbb Q$ and some $\rho$ quadratic in  $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$. Since we need
$$d(f(\omega))=f(\alpha\beta\gamma)=\alpha\beta\delta,$$
this gives us (as $d\rho=0$)
$$c\alpha\beta\gamma = \alpha\beta\delta$$
which is impossible (the algebra $A$ is free).
If $X$ is the corresponding rational homotopy type, its $\pi_1$ is $\mathbb Q^4$ (given by $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$, all four closed) and so the flip last 2 components of $\mathbb{Q}^4$, which is an endomorphism of $\pi_1=\mathbb Q^4$, doesn't come from any endomorphism of $X$.
[With a bit of luck there is a manifold with $\pi_1=\mathbb Z^4$ and with suitable differential 1-forms $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ (recognizing the 4 generators of $\pi_1$) and with a 2-form $\omega$ satisfying the above given relations, which would make this answer a bit more "tactile", but I don't see it.]
edit I had to add a 4th generator $\delta$ to make it (hopefully) correct and included a calculation showing that such an $f$ cannot exist.

Wow how brilliant! If you don't care, can you a bit explain more about dgca, cause I don't know where to search for it. Is it a method of constructing a space having such algebra?

@Noone The construction of $X$ is: for every $n$ take the algebra $\Omega(\Delta_n)$ of polynomial differential forms on the $n$-simplex with rational coefficients, and then the set $X_n$ of all dgca morphisms $A\to\Omega(\Delta_n)$. $X_n$'s form a simplicial set, $X$ is its geometric realization. This is a bit too much if you see it for the 1st time; the keyword is Rational homotopy theory.

dgca = differential graded-commutative algebra (in case it wasn't clear)

The space with this algebra is closely related to $(\mathbb{T}^3)^{(2)}$, the $2$-skeleton of the $3$-torus. (Edit: probably more closely related to $(\mathbb{T}^3)^{(2)} \times \mathbb{S}^{1}$ I suppose.) I myself had been thinking about a similar space (actually, a similar CDGA) to this recently, and there's a strong connection there. It's definitely NOT $(\mathbb{T}^3)^{(2)}$ itself, but regardless that might help you see where some of the strange interaction between the algebra and its topological/geometric realization is coming in.

Let $X=\mathbb{R}P^2 \times \mathbb{R}P^3$ and let $\theta$ be the automorphism of $\pi_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ interchanging the factors.  Then $\theta$ cannot be realised geometrically as on mod $2$ cohomology it takes an element whose cube is $0$, to one whose cube is not $0$.

Could you elaborate a bit on that second sentence? Assume I know the definition of cohomology and nothing else.

@NaïmFavier Let $s,t$ be the generators of $H^1(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}), H^1(\mathbb{R}P^3;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ respectively.  Let $f$ induce $\theta$ on $\pi_1(X)$.  Then $$0=f^(s^3)=f^(s)^3=t^3\neq0.$$
